# Ruby on Rails Devise Edit Registration Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Ruby 2.0.0 and Rails 4.0.2. When I click the submit button on the edit profile page, I get this routing error:

Routing Error

No route matches [PATCH] "/users/sign_in"

I do not exactly understand how the devise routing works since the only relevant line in the routes.rb file I see is devise_for :users. Here are some of my files. Thank you.

/config/routes.rb

```
SampleApplication::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :pins

  devise_for :users

  root 'pages#home'
  get 'about' => 'pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'pages#contact'

end
```

/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, #:recoverable, 
        :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :pins
end
```

/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb

```
<h2>Edit <%= resource_name.to_s.humanize %></h2>

<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), html:          {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>

  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <%= f.input :password, label: "New Password", autocomplete: "off" %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation, label: "New Password", autocomplete: "off" %>
  <%= f.input :current_password %>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-primary"%>
  </div>
<% end %>

<h3>Cancel my account</h3>

<p>Unhappy? <%= link_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), :confirm => "Are      you sure?", :method => :delete %>.</p>

<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
```

rake routes command

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
                    pins GET    /pins(.:format)           pins#index
                         POST   /pins(.:format)           pins#create
                 new_pin GET    /pins/new(.:format)       pins#new
                edit_pin GET    /pins/:id/edit(.:format)  pins#edit
                     pin GET    /pins/:id(.:format)       pins#show
                         PATCH  /pins/:id(.:format)       pins#update
                         PUT    /pins/:id(.:format)       pins#update
                         DELETE /pins/:id(.:format)       pins#destroy
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)  devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)  devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format) devise/sessions#destroy
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)   devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)          devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)  devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)     devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)          devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)          devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)          devise/registrations#destroy
                    root GET    /                         pages#home
                   about GET    /about(.:format)          pages#about
                 contact GET    /contact(.:format)        pages#contact
```

Comment: Try doing a rake routes and posting it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your simple_form is pointing to the wrong submit url.

It says

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), html:          {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %
```

but the `url` should point to the `user_registration_path`, not `session_path`, so

```
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_registration_path(resource_name), html:          {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %
```

Comment: I changed session_path to registration_path and it worked. Thanks!